# Differential equation related to energy conservation and Newton's law of gravitation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I have been trying to determine, given the position of a point mass an initial distance $x_0$ from the surface of a spherically symmetric body with mass $M$ and radius $R$, the position of the point mass after a time $t$ has passed. Using Newton's law of gravitation (since the body is spherically symmetric we may treat it as a point mass) and the principle of conservation of energy I have set up the following differential equation:
$$-\frac{GM}{R+x_0}+\frac{v_0^2}{2}=-\frac{GM}{R+x(t)}+\frac{\dot x^2(t)}{2},x(0)=x_0$$
Assuming that I set this up correctly (it's been a bit since I studied any mechanics), I now need to solve this differential equation.

**Attempt:** We can rearrange this equation a bit:
$$GM\left(\frac{1}{R+x}-\frac{1}{R+x_0}\right)+\frac{v_0^2}{2}=\frac{\dot x^2}{2}$$
$$\frac{GM(x_0-x)}{(R+x)(R+x_0)}+\frac{v_0^2}{2}=\frac{\dot x^2}{2}$$
$$\frac{2GM(x_0-x)+v_0^2(R+x)(R+x_0)}{2(R+x)(R+x_0)}=\frac{\dot x^2}{2}$$
$$\dot x=\pm\sqrt\frac{2GM(x_0-x)+v_0^2(R+x)(R+x_0)}{(R+x)(R+x_0)}$$
$$\dot x\sqrt\frac{(R+x)(R+x_0)}{2GM(x_0-x)+v_0^2(R+x)(R+x_0)}=\pm1$$
Now this is in a position to be integrated; the integration is messy but it does yield a general solution. However, trying to find a particular solution poses problems. Mathematica will not return a solution with the given initial condition. Is there a method of finding a particular solution to this differential equation (or an approximation)?

Comment: It looks like a [two body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_two-body_problem). Do you suppose that your body of mass $M$ is immobile?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Yes, we may assume that the mass of the mobile body is negligible relative to the mass of the larger body. The scenario I had in mind was of a spacecraft moving relative to a (nonatmospheric) planet.

Comment: Then you can use [Kepler laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion), and (if you speak Russian), there is a good write-up on how to solve this problem in this wiki article: (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB)

Comment: In other words, you try to find the solution as an ellipse, and try to fit its parameters to the initial data. Also, why do you measure distance as $R+x$? Should it be simply $x$?

Comment: The problem, as posed, appears to be in one dimension.  If you treat it as the limit, as angular momentum goes to zero, of the 2-D Kepler problem, you are faced with the issue of how to take that limit to get the 1-D motion.  This makes the question quite valid and non-trivial, even if you know the closed-form solution to the Kepler orbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is not a familiar function of $t$.  Here, I present a series representing the starting motion; it probably does not converge when $t$ is big enough to crash into $R+x=0$.

You can make the problem (assuming $v_0 = 0$) a bit more tractable by the following scaling transformations:

Work with $u = MG(R+x)$ adn $\tau = MGt$.  This rescaling makes the equation into 
$$\frac{d^2 u}{d\tau^2} = - \frac1{u^2}$$
with $u'(0) = 0$ and $u(0) = MG(R+x_0) \equiv u_0$.

Then transform again to a time variable $s = \frac{\tau}{u_0^{3/2}$.

When you do this, and expand as  a series by writing
$$
u(s) = u_0 \sum a_n s_n
$$
you find that $a_n = 0$ for odd $n$ (this is not surprising, because if you throw the object upward, the motion is symmetric about the time it comes to a stop).  Of course, $a_0 = 1$.  For even terms, 
$$
a_{2n} = - \frac{D_n}{(2n)!} 
$$
where $D_n$ refers to the sequence presented in OEIS as sequence A120419, where the sequence with positive instead of negative coefficients is related to the soluction of an integral equation.