# Does a closed-form solution to this nonlinear ODE exist?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''y^2=C\\\text{Where}\,\,y=y(x),\,C\in\mathbb R$$

This is a simplified differential equation that takes into account the decrease in gravitational acceleration that an object experiences as it moves away from a gravitational source.

Does it have a closed-form solution?

This is my first time asking a question here, so please let me know if I missed any required information or format. Thank you.

Comment: [Check Wolfy.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27+*+y%5E2+%3D+1)

Comment: You could first establish the conservation of energy: $$y'y''=\frac{C}{y^2}y'$$ $$\tfrac12y'^2=\frac{-C}{y}+E$$

Comment: This question, free fall on a straight line to the center, appears every few months. Just checking out the right-bar "Related" section finds https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483248/function-where-second-derivative-is-equal-to-reciprocal-squared

Answer (score 0):

$$y''\, y^2=C$$

Switching variables
$$-\frac{x''}{[x']^3}\, y^2=C$$

Reduction of order $p=x'$ gives
$$p=\pm \sqrt{\frac{y}{c_1 \,y-2 C}}$$
One more integration
$$x+c_2=\pm \int \sqrt{\frac{y}{c_1 \,y-2 C}}\,dy$$

$$y=\frac{2 C t^2}{c_1 t^2-1}\qquad \implies \qquad dy=-\frac{4 C t}{\left(c t^2-1\right)^2}\,dt$$

$$x+c_2=-4C \int \frac{ t^2}{\left(c_1 t^2-1\right)^2}\,dt$$
$$x+c_2=\pm 4 C \left(\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(t\sqrt{c_1}\right)}{2
   c_1^{3/2}}+\frac{t}{2 c_1 \left(c_1 t^2-1\right)}\right)$$

No hope to reverse this result.